# Issue with apply gradient color for window background in titanium

Tags: css, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, tss

I need to design window background with shades.  SO I tried with background gradients, But I'm not getting what I expected,

My code,

```
".questionsContainer":{
    height:Ti.UI.FILL,
    width:Ti.UI.FILL,
    layout:'vertical',
    backgroundGradient: {
            type: "linear",
            startPoint: { x: "0%", y:"0%"},
            endPoint:   { x: "0%", y:"100%"},
            colors: [
                { color: "#3C3C3C", offset: 0.0 },//302E2E
                { color: "#696969", offset: 1.0 }
            ]
        }
}
```

I tried this,
But I need to apply the styles similar to following code,

```
 background-image:
    radial-gradient(
      #C0C0C0,
      #696969
    );
```

How to apply this styles in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an open bug report on this problem [Cannot apply backgroundGradient via alloy.globals](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-4758). So, I think you may have to find a workaround until it is resolved.